# Как проверять валидность только изменямого атрибута?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть модель `user`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...

  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 8 }

  has_secure_password
  ...
```

Нужно сделать метод смены email'a.

Сделал в контроллере метод :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
...

def update_email
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(user_email_params)
    flash[:success] = "Адрес электронной почты изменен"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'settings'
  end
end
...
private

  def user_email_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email)
  end
```

В таком варианте он не работает, так как при вызове `update_email`, выводит ошибку из-за невалидности пароля. Если использовать `user.update_attribute(...)` или `user.save!`, не проверяется валидность изменяемого атрибута.

Как сделать так, что бы валидность пароля не проверялась, а проверялась только валидность `email`?

Есть ли какое-то решение средствами rails или остается только написать собственный метод проверки валидности и использовать его вместе с `.save!`?

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться условиями для валидации `if/unless`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  attr_accessor_with_default :ignore_password_validation, false

  validates :password, length: { minimum: 8 }, unless: :ignore_password_validation
```

Тогда метод контроллера будет следующим:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
...
  def update_email
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_email_params.merge(ignore_password_validation: true))
      flash[:success] = "Адрес электронной почты изменен"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'settings'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

В модели можно создать группу валидаций. Например:

```
validation_group :email do
  validates_presence_of :email
end
```

Затем, в контроллере написать следующее:

```
def update_email
  @user.email = params[:email]
  @user.update_attribute(:email, params[:email]) if @user.group_valid?(:email)
end
```

Метод `group_valid?(:email)` - выполняет описанную в модели группу валидаций `:email`
Метод `update_attribute` - сохраняет поле минуя валидации

Comment: Установил гем https://github.com/adzap/grouped_validations, сделал validation_group. Но он не работает и выдает ошибку  NoMethodError: undefined method `_run_validate_name_callbacks' for #<User:0x000000036e2398>

Comment: @ИльдарШарифуллин Обнови вопрос - выложив содержимое модели, и контроллера(либо, экшена, который сохраняет Email)

Answer (score -1):

Если это devise, то все есть в wiki
[Обновление без пароля](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password)

Так же можно указать конкретный action для валидации с помощью опции
[on:](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on)

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее ваше решение. Можно включить пример кода, объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п. Подробный и качественный ответ поможет гораздо большему количеству людей, столкнувшихся с подобной проблемой.

Comment: Это не Devise. Хелпер `has_secure_password` из ActiveRecord. А к `on` можно бы и привести маленький примерчик, а не отсылать по ссылке, которая может однажды умереть.